# SSHを使い、さくらサーバー内の日本語名ファイルを含むWordPressディレクトリをtar圧縮すると文字化けする

Tags: ssh

さくらサーバー(FreeBSD)内にある日本語名ファイルを含むWordPressディレクトリーをSSHでtar圧縮しエックスサーバーにFTP転送し解凍すると、日本語名ファイルのみ文字化けします。

原因が分かりません。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 双方のロケールの設定はどうなっていますでしょうか？ （`locale`コマンドなどで確認できます）

Answer (score 1):

何を使用して解凍しているかわかりませんが、
まずは切り分けとして、
圧縮したサーバーで、展開しても文字化けはしていないですか？
おそらく化けることは無いと思います。

解凍した先はWindowsですか？
それであれば解凍ソフトが対応していないか、
解凍時の設定だと思います。

圧縮時はutf8で、解凍先はSJISなので化けます。

最悪、圧縮せずにFTPでディレクトリごと持ってくるのが良いかと思います。

※追記
かなり古いですが下記のようなものがあります。
「http://www.csdinc.co.jp/archiver/lib/tar32.html」

※追記
Windows7以降であればPowerShellのtarコマンドから、
文字化けしないで解凍できるようです。
自分も知りませんでしたorz